# Laravel 5.2 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Tags: php, forms, laravel, upload, laravel-5

I am creating a video upload system and when I submit a video it shows to me:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

I have this in my view:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('video/upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="video">Video</label>
                <input type="file" id="video" name="video" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group text-lg-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

And this in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Video;

use App\Http\Requests;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
    public function upload()
    {
        return view('video.upload');
    }

    public function uploadPost(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|unique:videos|max:100',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'video' => 'required'
        ]);

        $mime = $request->file('video')->getMimeType();

        dd($mime);
    }
}
```

And my php.ini is:

> upload_max_filesize = 100M

Therefore, I have php.ini, csrf_field() and still getting error. What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you restart your web server after making the change to your php.ini?

Comment: And what is your `post_max_size` ?

Comment: Was 8M, I've changed it to 100M and it worked fine. Post it as an answer :D Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_max_size` also needs to be raised, since it's throwing a `POST Content-Length` error.

Comment: This was the absolute solution since it was 8M and I've changed it to 100M along with upload_max_filesize. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `{{ csrf_field() }}` to `{!! csrf_field() !!}`.

By default, Laravel will escape any data injected into templates. By surrounding the call to `csrf_field` in `{!! !!}` tags, you are telling Laravel *not* to escape the HTML markup generated by the `csrf_field()` function.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('video/upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="video">Video</label>
                <input type="file" id="video" name="video" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group text-lg-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please check view source in browser output of {!! csrf_field() !!} should be similar to  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="7FCrPHEAG9pNUEgEm6mAwSDLcSFF4s9BQzNbCCvY">

Comment: Is the same in both ways!

Comment: except value attribute other should be same.

Comment: there is another way too but Its not good in terms of security. You can specify in verify token middleware to exclude token checking in 'video/upload' route by  adding this code in App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php file 
    protected $except = [
        'video/upload'
    ];

Comment: Please check post_max_size variable value in php.ini file its should be post_max_size=100M

Answer (score -1):

this may help you

```
<input name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" type="hidden">
```

Add this in your form

Comment: Did you see this in his form?  `{{ csrf_field() }}` it does the same thing